# spread single key against multiple values

Tags: r

I have data frame as follows:
Actual data runs into hundreds of rows and columns

The objective here is to spread "Attribute Value" against each of the column V1, V2,...VN.
That is dates that are appearing in column V1, should get spread into column names
And corresponding "Attribute Value" should appear against each below

```
              df1 <- data.frame(ROW_ID = c("23416","23416","23416"),
              Process_ID = c("SLT","SLT","SLT"),
              Operation_Code = c("SLT","SLT","SLT"),
              Resource_Group_Code = c("BD","BD","BT"),
              Location_Code = c("JS","JS","JS"),
              Resource_Code = c("B-T234","B-T234","B-T234"),
              Resource_Desc = c("699","699","699"),
              iDeleteFlag = c("N","N","N"),
              Attribute_Code = c("RA002","RA002","RA002"),
              Attribute_Value = c("266","269","298"),
              Capacity_Type = c("s","s","s"),
              Planning_Version = c("PDMT","PDMT","PDMT"),
             "V1"= c("2021-10-10", "2021-10-31", "2021-11-07"),
             "V2"= c("2021-10-17", "", "2021-11-14"),
             "V3" = c("2021-10-24", "", "2021-11-21"),
             "V4" = c("", "2021-11-07", ""),
             "V5" = c("", "2021-11-21", ""))
```

The required output is as follows:

```
              df2 <- data.frame(ROW_ID = c("23416","23416","23416"),
              Process_ID = c("SLT","SLT","SLT"),
              Operation_Code = c("SLT","SLT","SLT"),
              Resource_Group_Code = c("BD","BD","BT"),
              Location_Code = c("JS","JS","JS"),
              Resource_Code = c("B-T234","B-T234","B-T234"),
              Resource_Desc = c("699","699","699"),
              iDeleteFlag = c("N","N","N"),
              Attribute_Code = c("RA002","RA002","RA002"),
                               Capacity_Type = c("s","s","s"),
              Planning_Version = c("PDMT","PDMT","PDMT"),
              "2021-10-10"= c("266", "", ""),
              "2021-10-17"= c("266", "", ""),
              "2021-10-24" = c("266", "", ""),
              "2021-10-31" = c("", "269", ""),
              "2021-11-07" = c("", "269", "298"),
              "2021-11-14" = c("", "", "298"),
              "2021-11-21" = c("", "269", "298"))
```

My code is as follows:
my code not giving required output

```
                       RA002variable_2021ANeg <- gather(RA002variable_2021ANeg, key, value, - 
                       ROW_ID, - Process_ID, - Operation_Code, - Resource_Group_Code, -
                       Location_Code, - Resource_Code, - Resource_Desc, -
                       iDeleteFlag, - Attribute_Code1, - Capacity_Type, -
                       Planning_Version, -Attribute_Value) %>%
                       mutate(key =(  Attribute_Value)) %>%
                       select(- Attribute_Value) %>%
                       spread(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gather and spread have been substituted with `pivot_longer`and `pivot_wider`. While gather and spread are still working, it's best we all got used to the new functions.

Since your `ROW_ID` is not unique for each row, I create additional index column (simply the row number), gather columns V1:V5 and spread dates into column names:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(V1:V5, names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  filter(value != "") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "value", values_from = "Attribute_Value")
```

Comment: Also consider dropping `index` column if you don't need it in the end

Comment: Hi, I m getting following error                                                                                                   Error in select(., -name) : unused argument (-name)                                                                          please help

Comment: @ksramana, `select(-name)`, not `select(., -name)`

Comment: hi,                                                                                                                                                 whether I use select(.,-name) or select(-name)                                                                            the error is same                                                                                                                       Error in select(., -name) : unused argument (-name)

Comment: hi, got resolved by using dlyr::select(-name)